# I want to make my html button work with php

Tags: php, html

I created a button using html, and using `array_key_exists` to call the function function from  php when button is pressed but it doesn't do anything 
`executeBoundSQL` is just a function from php

```
<form method="POST" action="docAppts.php">
<!--refresh page when submit-->

<p><input type="text" name="did" size="6">
<!--define two variables to pass the value-->
<input type="submit" value="search" name="searchh"></p>
</form>



if ($db_conn) {
$result=executePlainSQL(" select * from doctor");
printResult($result);
if (array_key_exists('searchh', $_POST)) {
    echo"show me";
    $tuple=array(
         ":bind1"=> $_POST['did']
    );
    $alltuples=array(
         $tuple
    );
    echo "<br> print table <br>";
//  executePlainSQL("Drop table :tablname");
    //echo':tablename';
    $result=executeBoundSQL("select * from doctor where  did=:bind1", $alltuples);

    printResult1($result);
    // Create new table...
    //echo "<br> creating new table <br>";
    //executePlainSQL("create table tab1 (nid number, name varchar2(30), primary key (nid))");
    OCICommit($db_conn);

} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting arrays with this:

```
$alltuples=array(
     $tuple
);
```

I'm not sure what database API you're using, but I'm willing to bet it's not going to recursively search for bind parameters.

[image: annotated recursive array diagram]

Since you only have one bind, then it's sufficient to just pass `$tuple` to it.

```
$result=executeBoundSQL("select * from doctor where  did=:bind1", $tuple);
```

If you have more parameters that you need to bind, then simply add them to the same array:

```
$tuple=array(
     ":bind1"=> $_POST['did'],
     ":bind2"=> $_POST['did2'],
     ":bind3"=> $_POST['did3']
);
```

Or you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$tuple=array(
     ":bind1"=> $_POST['did']
);

$tuple2=array(
     ":bind2"=> $_POST['did2']
);

$alltuples=array_merge(
     $tuple,$tuple2
);
```

All of your bind parameters *should* be uniquely named, but it's still interesting to note behavior on key collisions with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Comment: thanks, this is so helpful ,I am just beginner of php

Comment: just asked another question, if you can help it would be greatful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800431/displaying-all-records-in-a-statement-php